# How to change the col type of a BigQuery repeated record

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to change a col type of a repeated record from `STRING` to `TIMESTAMP`. There are a few suggestions from BQ docs here ([manually-changing-schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type)). However, I'm running into issues with each of the recommended suggestions.

Here is an example schema:

```html
{
  'name' => 'id',
  'type' => 'STRING',
  'mode' => 'REQUIRED'
},
{
  'name' => 'name',
  'type' => 'STRING',
  'mode' => 'REQUIRED'
},
// many more fields including nested records and repeated records
{
  'name' => 'locations',
  'type' => 'RECORD',
  'mode' => 'REPEATED',
  'fields' => [
    {
      'name' => 'city',
      'type' => 'STRING',
      'mode' => 'REQUIRED'
    },
    {
      'name' => 'updated_at',
      'type' => 'STRING',   // ** want this as TIMESTAMP **
      'mode' => 'REQUIRED'
    },
  ]
}
```

**Issue with using Query:**

I think we'd have to UNNEST the repeated record, cast the field to timestamp for each repeated record and then somehow recreate the row for insertion into the new table.

**Issue with exporting table as JSON:**

When exporting the table in JSON format it exports raw json representations of the data (with maps and dictionaries, as we'd expect it to).

However, we're not able to import that raw data back into BQ:

> BigQuery does not support maps or dictionaries in JSON. For example,
>   "product_categories": {"my_product": 40.0} is not valid, but
>   "product_categories": {"column1": "my_product" , "column2": 40.0} is
>   valid.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#limitations

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below answer is based on that:`REPEATED RECORD` type in BigQuery StandardSQL is represented as type `ARRAY<STRUCT<f1 f1_type, f2 f2_type ... >>`.

It is not my favorite since you have to specify full column list. Maybe there is a better way.

```sql
#standardSQL
-- Build sample data, try to mimic what's in question.
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  <your_dataset>.sample_table AS
SELECT name, 
       array<struct<city string, update_at string>>[("SFO", "2011-1-1"), ("SEA", "2022-2-2")] 
       as locations
FROM UNNEST(['Name1', "Name2", "Name3"]) as name;
```

[image]
[image]

Then below SQL will convert `update_at` column into `DATE` and save to new table (or the same one if you'd like).

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  <your_dataset>.output_table AS
SELECT * REPLACE (
   ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(CAST(update_at AS DATE) AS update_at)
         FROM UNNEST(locations)) 
   AS locations 
   )
FROM
  <your_dataset>.sample_table;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. in my sample code I oversimplified the data model; the repeated record we're dealing with has 30+ fields....  I guess I just need to bite the bullet and craft all types again for all of the fields

Comment: Good luck @harlow, I'm also looking for a better solution. But 30+ field is not a big deal, you might have had the work done already I guess.

Comment: @harlow, I updated my answer and you can find a slightly better solution at the bottom.

Comment: yep, thanks. that is much nicer! One thing that the new table unfortunately looses are the `NOT NULL` ('mode' => 'REQUIRED') constraints in the new table output. i.e. `id` and `name` we're required in the previous table, but the new table that's generate those aren't required

Comment: @harlow, I found out the answer how to avoid specify list of column at all. Please see updates. It still doesn't preserve 'REQUIRED' info though.

Comment: used this query to help re-generate the schema for the repeated record:

```
SELECT
 * EXCEPT(is_generated, generation_expression, is_stored, is_updatable)
FROM
 my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 table_name="my_table_name"
```

Comment: @harlow, for your future reference, there's existing example to generate `CREATE TABLE` statement from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. It doesn't seem to cover "REQUIRED" as of now, but I'll update it. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#advanced_example