# Change type of record column in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with a RECORD type column. This RECORD column is just a RECORD, it's not a REPEATED column. I would like to change the type of one of the elements in the record.  My record is defined as:

```
product_action                RECORD NULLABLE
product_action.action_type    INTEGER NULLABLE
product_action.checkout_step  INTEGER NULLABLE
```

I would like to change the type of ACTION_TYPE from INTEGER to STRING, but I don't know how to do it. I know it involves selecting and casting to a new table, but I don't know the right syntax. There is a very similar question here with an answer
[How to change the col type of a BigQuery repeated record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485264/how-to-change-the-col-type-of-a-bigquery-repeated-record)
but it's only for REPEATED records and was not able to change it to RECORD only (not REPEATED).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potential problem with OP's answer is that it does not preserve original order of fields in record, so it ends up with below schema

```
product_action                RECORD NULLABLE
product_action.checkout_step  INTEGER NULLABLE
product_action.action_type    STRING NULLABLE  <-- Type and position changed
```

instead of

```
product_action                RECORD NULLABLE
product_action.action_type    STRING NULLABLE  <-- Type changed while position preserved  
product_action.checkout_step  INTEGER NULLABLE
```

Below handles this issue

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE((
  SELECT AS STRUCT product_action.* REPLACE(
    CAST(product_action.action_type AS STRING) AS action_type
  )) AS product_action) 
FROM `mytable`
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working finally

```sql
SELECT
  * REPLACE   
      ( 
        (
            SELECT
            AS STRUCT product_action.* EXCEPT (action_type),
            CAST(product_action.action_type AS STRING) AS action_type
         ) AS product_action
      ),
FROM
  `mytable`
```

Comment: Just to complement the solution, here's the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-modifiers) for SELECT * REPLACE and SELECT * EXCEPT